# theard not responding while in mainloop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading, pyserial

I'm working on a project where when a button is press in my controller a string needs to appear on the GUI. so I used threading, pyserial and tkinter for the mission but everytime I press the button in my controller it doesnt work after mainloop works, send text to the controller works, the terminal is a class I bulit with variable channel for serial

```
def chat_menu(terminal):
 chat_window = Tk()
 chat_window.geometry("650x480")
 input_text = Text(chat_window, height=20, width=30)
 output_text = Text(chat_window, height=20, width=30)
 title = Label(chat_window, text="Chat Mode", font=("Arial", 
 14, "bold"))
 title_in = Label(chat_window, text="Input", font=("Arial", 14, 
"bold"))
 title_out = Label(chat_window, text="Output", font=("Arial", 
14, "bold"))
text = input_text.get("1.0", END)
submit_button = Button(chat_window, height=3, width=20, 
text="Submit",
                       font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'), 
command=lambda: send_text(terminal, chat_window, input_text))
back_button = Button(chat_window, height=3, width=20, 
text='Back', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'),
                     command=lambda: 
terminal.close_main(chat_window, 'd'))
terminal.data = None
title.grid(row=0, column=1)
input_text.grid(row=1, column=0)
output_text.grid(row=1, column=2)
title_in.grid(row=2, column=0)
title_out.grid(row=2, column=2)
submit_button.grid(row=3, column=0)
back_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_text(terminal, 
output_text))
thread.start()
mainloop()

def receive_text(terminal, output):
time.sleep(2)
received = False
while True:
    while terminal.channel.in_waiting > 0:
        received_dataterminal.channel.read_until(expected='\n')  
        output.insert(END, received_data.decode("ascii"))
        received = True
    if received:
        break
```

Comment: `while True:` interfers the mainloop till the whileloop stops. So after some time tkinter thinks the program is hanging.

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=receive_text(terminal, output_text))` should be `threading.Thread(target=receive_text, args=(terminal, output_text))`. You're calling `receive_text` in the main thread accidentally.

Comment: @Atlas435, I took the while True down, still doesn't respond

Comment: @DarkKnight35 didnt noticed the thread. So what Carcigenicate said.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I changed it but still doesnt respond, I checked the controller side, works perfect.

Comment: @DarkKnight35 Please fix the indentation and calling `tkinter` functions from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk()` is bad practice and can raise a lot of issues. So don't call `tkinter` function from other threads